# Colorbox lightbox - should 'lightboxed page' be a complete page

Tags: javascript, lightbox, colorbox

I am having some difficulties with a form that is part of a lightbox page. On some versions of IE people are reporting that the form is not sending.

I am wondering if I have implemented the lightbox correctly. I am using Colorbox.

Can somone please tell me..

- am I supposed to treat the page that
     is being lightbox as a complete page?
     i.e should it have a doctype, html,
     body tags?
- should I be referencing
     jquery on both the parent page AND  the lightbox page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lightbox is a separate page, implimented as an iframe, then it needs to be a complete page, and the form should work, leading to the results of the form loading in the iframe.

You don't need jQuery on a page because it is displayed in an iframe, but you may need it for other reasons (form validation, for example).

Comment: Thanks. I thought that was the case.